# Populating a keyword drop-down menu from a sqlite database using python

Tags: python, database, sqlite, drop-down-menu

I'm relatively new to python and my title pretty much says it all. I looked on here and the closest I could find was done in PHP and not python.

The code that I got written is to preform a search where clicking on a search button, searches my database for the keyword typed in a space provided and displays all corresponding url(s) with that keyword within it's row on my webpage.

Now I need the drop-down menu to populate on loading the page with all the keywords and being able to click on the keyword will preform the search just as typing in the keyword would. My drop-down will pull for columns k1-k13 that may or may not have have a text in it. I plan on using distinct to cut out any duplicate words and blank fields but wanted to at least to get it to work first. I do have the drop-down written in the XML.

Here is what I got:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2.7

import sys
import sqlite3
from string import Template
from cgi import FieldStorage
from dateutil import parser
from textwrap import dedent
from eicpy.www import CGIHandler
from eicpy.sql import ezsql

from eicpy import www
from eicpy import cgierror
cgierror.enable(display=True)

DB = ezsql().connect("/usr/HTTPServer/dev7/data/asq1.db")

class Page(CGIHandler):

def handle1(self):
   search_terms = self.fs.getfirst("searchinp", None)
   if search_terms:
      fields = search_terms.split(" ")
      steps = []
      apps = []

      for field in fields:
        recs = DB.execute("select issue, url, steps from help where k1='%s' or
        k2='%s' or k3='%s' or k4='%s' or k5='%s' or k6='%s' or k7='%s' or
        k8='%s' or k9='%s' or k10='%s' or k11='%s' or k12='%s' or k13='%s'" %
        (field, field, field, field, field, field, field, field, field, field,
         field, field, field)).fetchall()

#self.debug(recs)

for r in recs:
  if r.steps == "S":
    steps.append({
    "issue" : r.issue,
    "size" : "600x460",
    "location" : "/" + r.url
    })

if r.steps =="A":
    apps.append({
    "issue" : r.issue,
    "size" : "600x460",
    "location" : "/" + r.url
    })

#self.debug(steps)
#self.debug(apps)

self.show({"steps": steps, "apps": apps})

else :
   self.show({})

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = Page('Agent Support Query'
        ,'pt/asq.xml'
        , ['/styles/asq.css'])
    p.handle1()
```

Comment: Which web framework are you using? I'm not familiar with eicpy. Typically this is the sort of thing you accomplish with a template engine (e.g. Mako or Jinja2).

Comment: being for work, there is a template that we start with, we use python/cgi-bin. it's what I have to use. I know there might be better options but I work with what I got.